# Html5/Css3 Оптимизация сайтов под мобильные устройства

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

*Добрый вечер, форумчане Stackoverflow, недавно появилась проблема касательно оптимизации сайтов под мобильные устройства.*

**Суть проблемы заключается в том, что сайт при повороте экрана начинает некорректно отображаться и все блоки съезжают со своих привычных мест.**

Есть ли способ решить проблему, чтобы при повороте экрана сайт отображался нормально на мобильных устройствах и планшетах, но не задевал при этом разрешения ноутбуков и планшетов?

Comment: оптимизация - трудоемкий процесс. для этого, как правило, используют css медиа: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Comment: Я знаю, что их используют, я сам с ними работаю, но я не понимаю, как можно оптимизировать экран телефона/планшета, когда он повёрнут, какой мета тег можно использовать.

Comment: так вы дочитайте хоть до середины справочник. при помощи `@media orientation`